# Django: sorting by datetime field is only accurate to minutes, not seconds?

Tags: python, django, time, django-queryset

Is there a way to make Django consider seconds (and even milliseconds) ordering a queryset by a DateTime field?

I want to display a table with the results of my blood tests ordered in reverse chronological order. It works, as long as tests aren't added in the same minute. If they are only separated by seconds, they are listed in chronological order for the duration of that minute.

```
models.py
class BloodTest(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BLOOD_TEST_CHOICES, 
        default=BILIRUBIN)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=10)        
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), validators= 
        [validate_date])

views.py
def blood_list(request, blood_id):
    blood = BloodTest.objects.get(id=blood_id)
    patient = blood.patient
    blood_list = BloodTest.objects.filter(name=blood.name).filter(patient=patient.id).order_by('-time')
    context = {'blood_list': blood_list, 'patient': patient, 'blood': blood}
    return render(request, 'vitals/blood-list.html', context)

blood-list.html template
{% for blood in blood_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ blood.time }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'blood' blood.id %}">{{ blood.value }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: A DateTimeField in internally a timestamp and should be at least accurate to milliseconds, also when it comes to sorting. So why do you think the seconds are not taken into account?

Comment: I agree, that's how I'm expecting it to behave. However, in practice, with the code I've displayed above, it works to display the results in reverse chronological order to minutes, but reverts to chronological order if several tests are added in the same minute. I'm not quite sure why this is happening...

Comment: Since the sorting is done by the database we would need the type and version of your database, your data and the output.